# Provider Hosted app not working on other pc by accessing url

Tags: 2013, error, sharepoint-addin

I have created a Provider Hosted app. I have created it by using self signed certificate. I followed the steps given in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/fp179901.aspx) site.

The app is working fine on my machine. It is also visible in my `Site Content`. But when I have debug and run it from the visual studio by pressing F5.

When other machine which is member of this server try to access this app from `Site Content` it gives an error like follows.

[image]

It try to fetch the URL of `localhost` from other machine.

How can I make my app accessible to all machine which are connected to my server machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your provider hosted app is ready for Testing/Production then it's time to deploy the ASP.NET part like any other ASP.NET web application. A good starting point for learning this is [ASP.NET/Web Forms/Overview/Chapter 10. Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment).

When the ASP.NET part is deployed then you should change the StartPage in the AppManifest.xml to point to the new location of the ASP.NET site.

If you just want to test the application on other machines in your network, then you can just change your ASP.NET project to use IIS on your machine (see [Web Servers in Visual Studio for ASP.NET Web Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx)) instead of a full deployment. But you still need to change the AppManifest.xml to have the right url.

Comment: In my AppManifest.xml file the Start Page url is like "~remoteAppUrl/Page/Temp.aspx" So what should I change to make it run...

Comment: You should change ~remoteAppUrl to the URL where your app is hosted. In production this would be something like https://www.contoso.com/myapp in testing it could be http://yourmachine:1234, but that depends on how you configure the binding in IIS

Comment: I change my URL in manifest file but it is not working. when i run my project to my machine it runs on localhost because of "~remoteAppUrl" but when I remove it and put my SPSite URL in that it again give me error that page not found...

Comment: It should not be the URL of your SharePoint site, but the URL of the ASP.NET site. This may be http://localhost:44307 as long as you only want to be able to access it on your machine, but when you want to access it on another machine it must be a real URL. `localhost` **is always the machine where the brower is running**

Comment: Ohk.. I am trying to solve this... Actually I am manipulating SharePoint List data in my App that is why I am using sharepoint site...

Comment: Hey Per Jakobsen, Can you help me in one thing that I want to know before I publish my app for SharePoint Online that I changed my ClientID and ClientSecret in Web.Config file do I have to change ClientID in AppManifest file. Because in that file It shows "*" in ClientID. Should I change that.?

Comment: Yes the ClientID in AppManifest should be updated to match Web.Config and Seller Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

When you publish the provider hosted app at that time you will have app file as well as web application project. you have to publish your web application and have to pass the URL of the web application to the app manifest file and after that put your app file to the appcatalog of your site and use the app.